AzureAD module not importing/loading binaries
I recently cloned the following repo from github which has a bunch of really useful API calls and functions that allow managing devices via Intune much easier. I'm have very little experience with Azure and PowerShell, and keep getting the following errors:
Line |
  87 |  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'C:\User\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'. The system cannot find the file     
     | specified."
MethodInvocationException: C:\Users\Desktop\PS_Scripts\powershell-intune-samples-master\ManagedDevices\ManagedDevices_DeviceOwnership_Set.ps1:89:1
Line |
  89 |  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms) | Out-Null
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.182\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll'. The system cannot find the 
     | file specified."
Cannot find type [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I have already installed and loaded the AzureAD module via elevated PowerShell prompt and verified that the install was successful. However, when installing the module, the specified binaries: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform aren't downloaded along with everything else. I tried to copy over the same binaries that were installed via Visual Studio for a different project but that seemed to cause more errors.

What were the new errors after downloading the dlls?  Most likely the dlls were built with a different version of Net than was on the machine.  The best way of solving is to publish the dll project(s) and then install the dlls with the setup that is created by publishing.  Or you could attempt to install the same version of Net that the dlls were built.

Check if this work link

Let me check it out!

@jdweng I think the main issue is with my local admin rights on my work computer. I have access to an elevated PowerShell now so will test again.

The file is in User/Documents which means you created an account "Documents".  Only the account and an Admin has access to the folder.

I remove my usernames and path location because it is a company computer and contains company names.
